# Disable the next step wizard?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue where in my project there a sequence of four steps of the form and when ever the user clicks on the Proceed button it's has to go for the next step. But in my coding I can see by clicking upon the number with step 2,3,4 are clickable. It shouldn't be clickable until the user press Proceed button. And when ever the user goes for last step 4 the previous steps should not be clickable.

Please find the below image what I exactly my issue is of.

[Click on the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7VSI.png)

Can anybody give me a solution where am going wrong in coding.

Below is my HTML Code:

```
<div class="row">
        <div align="center" class="col-md-12">
            <div class="mainform">

                <div class="container" style="max-width:600px;">
                    <div class="stepwizard">
                       <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">
                          <div class="stepwizard-step col-xs-3"> 
                            <a href="#step-1" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-circle">1</a>
                             <p><small>Step 1</small></p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="stepwizard-step col-xs-3"> 
                             <a href="#step-2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">2</a>
                             <p><small>Step 2</small></p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="stepwizard-step col-xs-3"> 
                             <a href="#step-3" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">3</a>
                              <p><small>Step 3</small></p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="stepwizard-step col-xs-3"> 
                             <a href="#step-4" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">4</a>
                              <p><small>Step 4</small></p>
                          </div>

                         </div>
                     </div>
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                       <form role="form">
                           <div class="panel panel-primary setup-content" id="step-1" style="background: rgb(48, 64, 135);">
                              <div style="padding: 20px 10px;">
                                  <h3 class="panel-title" style="color: #f2a495;"><strong>Enter Your Details</strong></h3>
                              </div>
                               <div class="panel-body">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="name" class="control-label col-sm-3 mob">Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                      <input type="text" id="name" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name" />
                                    </div>
                                  <div class="col-sm-4 mob1">
                                     <input id="lname" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name" />
                                  </div>
                              </div>

                             <div class="form-group">
                                 <label for="mobile" class ="control-label col-sm-3 mob">Mobile</label>
                                   <div class="col-sm-8">
                                       <input type="tele" maxlength="10" required="required" class="form-control" id="number" placeholder="Enter Your Mobile Number">
                                   </div>
                             </div>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                 <label for="mobile" class ="control-label col-sm-3 mob">Email</label>
                             <div class="col-sm-8">
                                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="number" required="required" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
                              </div>
                            </div>

                          <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn" type="button" style="width:25% !important;letter-spacing:1px !important;">Proceed</button>
                       </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel panel-primary setup-content" id="step-2" style="background: rgb(48, 64, 135);">
                        <div style="padding: 20px 10px;">
                            <h3 class="panel-title" style="color: #f2a495;"><strong>Enter Your Details</strong></h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                               <label class="col-sm-3 control-label mob">Gender</label>
                               <div class="col-sm-6">
                                   <div class="radio-inline">
                                       <label style="color:#fff;">
                                          <input style="color:#fff !important;" type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked/> Male
                                       </label>
                                   </div>
                                <div class="radio-inline">
                                   <label style="color:#fff;">
                                      <input style="color:#fff !important;" type="radio" name="gender" value="female" /> Female
                                   </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="radio-inline">
                                  <label style="color:#fff;">
                                    <input style="color:#fff !important;" type="radio" name="gender" value="Other" /> Other
                                  </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-3">DOB</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input name="dob" id="dob" required="required" required="" aria-required="true" class="form-control" type="date">
                               </div>
                         </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                           <label class="control-label col-sm-3 mob">Address</label>
                               <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Enter Your Address"></textarea>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="col-sm-3 control-label mob">City</label>
                               <div class="col-sm-8">
                                      <select class="form-control" id="gender4">
                                      <option value="Select City">Enter Your City Name</option>
                                      <option value="Ahmedabad">Ahmedabad</option>
                                      <option value="Ahmednagar">Ahmednagar</option>
                                      <option value="Bengaluru">Bengaluru</option>
                                      <option value="Bhopal">Bhopal</option>
                                      <option value="Chandigarh">Chandigarh</option>
                                      <option value="Chennai">Chennai</option>
                                      <option value="Coimbatore">Coimbatore</option>
                                      <option value="Ghaziabad">Ghaziabad</option>
                                      <option value="Greater Noida">Greater Noida</option>
                                      <option value="Gurgaon">Gurgaon</option>
                                      <option value="Howrah">Howrah</option>
                                      <option value="Hubli">Hubli</option>
                                      <option value="Indore">Indore</option>
                                      <option value="Jaipur">Jaipur</option>
                                      <option value="Kolkata">Kolkata</option>
                                      <option value="Lucknow">Lucknow</option>
                                      <option value="Mangalore">Mangalore</option>
                                      <option value="Mohali">Mohali</option>
                                      <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
                                      <option value="Navi Mumbai">Navi Mumbai</option>
                                      <option value="New Delhi">New Delhi</option>
                                      <option value="Noida">Noida</option>
                                      <option value="Panchkula">Panchkula</option>
                                      <option value="Pune">Pune</option>
                                      <option value="Salem">Salem</option>
                                      <option value="Sangli">Sangli</option>
                                      <option value="Surat">Surat</option>
                                      <option value="Thane">Thane</option>
                                      <option value="Udaipur">Udaipur</option>
                                      <option value="Vadodara">Vadodara</option>
                                      </select>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="col-sm-3 control-label mob">PIN</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" required="required" maxlength="10" class="form-control" name="PIN" placeholder="Enter Your PIN Code"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn" type="button" style="width:25%;letter-spacing:1px !important;">Proceed</button>
                   </div>
             </div>

            <div class="panel panel-primary setup-content" id="step-3" style="background: rgb(48, 64, 135);">
                 <div style="padding: 20px 10px;">
                     <h3 class="panel-title" style="color: #f2a495;"><strong>Enter Your Details</strong></h3>
                 </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="address" class ="control-label col-sm-3 mob">Employment Type</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                     <select class="form-control">
                    <option>Employment Type</option>
                    <option  name="option" value="Salaried">Salaried</option>
                    <option  name="option" value="Self Employed">Self Employed</option>                     
                     </select>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="address" class ="control-label col-sm-3 mob">PAN Card Number</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="address" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="Enter Your PAN Card Number">
                     </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="email" class ="control-label col-sm-3 mob">Monthly Income</label>
                   <div class="col-sm-8">
                       <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your Monthly Income">
                   </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                 <div class="col-sm-12">
                     <div style="font-weight:bold; color:#fff;">Have you availed Loan Or Credit Card From Any Bank</div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-sm-12">
                   <div class="radio-inline">
                                       <label style="color:#fff;">
                                          <input style="color:#fff !important;" type="radio" name="gender" value="yes" checked/> Yes
                                       </label>
                                   </div>
                                <div class="radio-inline">
                                   <label style="color:#fff;">
                                      <input style="color:#fff !important;" type="radio" name="gender" value="no" /> No
                                   </label>
                                </div>
                  </div> 
                </div>
```

Below is my Javascript Code used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

var navListItems = $('div.setup-panel div a'),
    allWells = $('.setup-content'),
    allNextBtn = $('.nextBtn');

allWells.hide();

navListItems.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
        $item = $(this);

    if (!$item.hasClass('disabled')) {
        navListItems.removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-default');
        $item.addClass('btn-success');
        allWells.hide();
        $target.show();
        $target.find('input:eq(0)').focus();
    }
});

allNextBtn.click(function () {
    var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
        curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
        nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
        curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url']"),
        isValid = true;

    $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
    for (var i = 0; i < curInputs.length; i++) {
        if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid) {
            isValid = false;
            $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
        }
    }

    if (isValid) nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
});

$('div.setup-panel div a.btn-success').trigger('click');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Create a demo fiddle for better undertand

Comment: #manoj This is the link for the jsfiddle...  https://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/59e5e1ya/

Comment: the 2,3 and 4 are not clickable for me. what's your problem

Comment: #sagar In my above code it's clickable for me

Comment: @Riteu , also in code, that is not clickable

Comment: @Riteu: I found your jsfiddle and was using it as an example for my project and I see that Step 2/3/4 is clickable on my dev box (Mac Mojavev10.14.6] with Chrome, Safari & FF. But your jsfiddle works properly - they're disabled and not clickable until you fill in the required fields and click 'Next'. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: If I inspect the element on your jsfiddle it has this additional attribute: pointer-events: none. Adding that to the .btn.disabled class did the trick. No idea why this attribute shows up on your jsfiddle but not when I copy your stuff and deploy it locally.